# How to get value from attribute element

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

How To Get Value type = 'Microsoft Lumia'. 
This is output:

```
<phone>
<model type="Microsoft Lumia">
<lumia id="Lumia 650">
<displaySize>4 Inch</displaySize>
<platformOS>Windows</platformOS>
</lumia>
<lumia id="Lumia 890">
<displaySize>5 Inch</displaySize>
<platformOS>Windows</platformOS>
</lumia>
```

this is my syntax:

```
$roottag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("model")[0].getAttribute("type[contain='Microsoft Lumia']");
```

can somebody help me ! thanks in advance

Comment: _`$roottag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("model")[0]...`_ - is it PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't tagged the question with a programming language, but your code looks very much like PHP using the [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$roottag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("model")[0].getAttribute("type[contain='Microsoft Lumia']");
```

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that you don't know how to fetch a `model` element having `type` attribute with a value containing `'Microsoft Lumia'` string. This is easily done with the following XPath expression:

```
//model[contains(@type, 'Microsoft Lumia')]
```

The double slash selects all `model` elements in the document. The condition in square brackets filters out the result set by the test calling [`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function. The function checks if the `type` attribute value contains the given keyword.

Fortunately, the DOM extension supports XPath through its [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class. If your code is not PHP, you still can figure out the solution in your language. The general idea is to use XPath as shown above.

**Example in PHP**

The following example prints the `type` attribute values containing `Lumia` keyword.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<phone>
  <model type="Microsoft Lumia">
    <lumia id="Lumia 650">
      <displaySize>4 Inch</displaySize>
      <platformOS>Windows</platformOS>
    </lumia>
    <lumia id="Lumia 890">
      <displaySize>5 Inch</displaySize>
      <platformOS>Windows</platformOS>
    </lumia>
  </model>
  <model type="MS Lumia">
    <lumia id="X">
      <displaySize>5 Inch</displaySize>
      <platformOS>Windows</platformOS>
    </lumia>
  </model>
</phone>
XML;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains
$keyword = 'Lumia';
$models = $xpath->query("//model[contains(@type, '{$keyword}')]");
foreach ($models as $m) {
  printf(
    "«%s» contains «%s»\n",
    $m->getAttribute('type'),
    $keyword
  );
}
```

*Output*

```
«Microsoft Lumia» contains «Lumia»
«MS Lumia» contains «Lumia»
```

Comment: $roottag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("model")[0];//.getAttribute("type[contain='Microsoft Lumia']");
 $tolol = $roottag->getAttribute("type[contain='Microsoft Lumia']");

Comment: thank u very  much :) may god bless u. above is the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

you can get 'Microsoft Lumia' :

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("model")[0].getAttribute("type"));
```

**updated part:**
as your request in comment:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("model")[0].getAttribute("type");
  if(d == 'Microsoft Lumia'){
  alert(d);
 }
```

Comment: but what if i want to =="Microsoft Lumia" with something? sorry im too newbie in this area.